# C++ infinite loop issue

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

I am not sure what the issue may be.  I added "cout << count;" to the if statements to see why there is no return value 'val'.

But now I see there is an infinite loop occurring.

I'm essentially trying to count how many loops it takes for num = 0.

At first I thought it was num = count being in the loop.

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// hailstone function prototype
int hailstone(int &num);


int main()
{
    int val;

    cout << "Enter integer" << endl;
    cin >> val;

    hailstone(val);

    cout << val << endl;

    return 0;


}

// Pass values by reference to hailstone function header
int hailstone(int &num)
{   

    do
    {
        int count = 0;    

        // If num is even
        // Divide by two
        if(num % 2 == 0)
        {
            num = (num / 2);
            count++;
            cout << count;

        }

        // If num is odd
        // Multiply by 3 and add 1
        else if(num % 2 != 0)
        {
            num = (num * 3) + 1;
            count++;
            cout << count;

        }
    // Assign the number of steps to num
    num = count;

    } while(num > 0);

    // Return the number of steps
    return num;
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? count is always greater than 0 and at the end of loop you assign it to num so the loop goes on forever

Comment: Before you write the code for your algorithm, does your algorithm make sense? At a quick glance I can't see how `num` will ever decrement in the long term, even without the statement `num = count;` - you would have an infinite loop 1 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1 -> ... to echo @Pooya, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Just remove "num = count;" and replace "return num" with "return count" and you're golden - at least as golden as your even/odd algorithm will get you - but maybe you're really looking for num to go to 1, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here, but the most pertinent is this line:

```
// Assign the number of steps to num
num = count;
```

You're essentially resetting num after you update it based on the rules of the hailstone sequence. Because 'count' is initialized at the start of each loop and then iterated once in either the 'if' or 'else if' block, it is always one. Therefore, at the end of each loop, num is always 1.

Comment: "num is always 1"?

Comment: @xaxxon read his code. count is initialized to zero, incremented, and assigned to num during every loop. Therefore, num is always equal to 1.

Comment: yep, I missed the initialization inside the loop.,

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are doing `num = num/2;` (for even numbers) or `num = (num * 3) + 1` (for odd numbers), the number will never become `0 or less`. That's why your code runs for infinite time. So you need to change the line `while (num > 0);` to `while(num > 1);` inside the function `hailstone` (maybe it is line number 54). As like as follow:

**Old code:**

```
int hailstone(int &num)
{   

do
{
    int count = 0;    

    // If num is even
    // Divide by two
    if(num % 2 == 0)
    {
        num = (num / 2);
        count++;
        cout << count;

    }

    // If num is odd
    // Multiply by 3 and add 1
    else if(num % 2 != 0)
    {
        num = (num * 3) + 1;
        count++;
        cout << count;

    }
// Assign the number of steps to num
num = count;

} while(num > 0); //You need to change this line

// Return the number of steps
return num;
}
```

**New Code:**

```
int hailstone(int &num)
{   

do
{
    int count = 0;    

    // If num is even
    // Divide by two
    if(num % 2 == 0)
    {
        num = (num / 2);
        count++;
        cout << count;

    }

    // If num is odd
    // Multiply by 3 and add 1
    else if(num % 2 != 0)
    {
        num = (num * 3) + 1;
        count++;
        cout << count;

    }
// Assign the number of steps to num
num = count;

} while(num > 1); //Here is the change

// Return the number of steps
return num;
}
```

**Another issue:** You declares `num = count` (in line 52), which will not return the actual value (if your code is for counting number of loops). Example: If the input is **12** than the loop will run for **10** times but your code will print **11**, I don't think this line is required. Return the value of `count` variable after your `do-while` loop breaks.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

clearly either 'if' or 'else if' condition is going to be satisfied that will increment count to 1 , and assigning num =count makes num =1 ,so(num>0) is always true.so loop continues forever

Answer (score -2):

```
do
{
  int count = 0;    

  if (num % 2 == 0)
  {
    num = (num / 2);
    count++;
    cout << count;
  }
  else if(num % 2 != 0)
  {
    num = (num * 3) + 1;
    count++;
    cout << count;
  }

  num = count;

} while (num > 0);
```

Comment: Yes, I did. That should suffice.

Comment: Oh, you bolded the error?   That's rather subtle in my font and took more work than simply explaining the problem.   Pretty tacky, in my opinion